# Numeral in POS tag "whnp-1" mean?

Tags: parsing, nlp, linguistics, pos-tagger

I am trying to understand an already annotated the sentence *When this happens, the two KIMs show a magnetism that causes the first KIM to move toward the second KIM.*

What does number *1* in POS tag WHADVP-1 for *When* mean/signify?

Similarly what does number *1* in POS tag WHNP-1 for *that*  mean/signify?

I think I understand well POS tags, after reading http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/PennTreebankTags.html and
notes by Andrew McIntyre.

Answer (score 0):

They are indices for coreference resolution. I think [this guide](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~dm/07/autumn/795.10/ptb-annotation-guide/root.html) from the University of Tübingen, Germany puts it quite nicely.

> 4.1.2  Indexing
>
> Indices are used only when they can be used to indicate a relationship
>   that would otherwise not be unambiguously retrievable from the
>   bracketing. Indices are used to express such relationships as
>   coreference (as in the case of controlled PRO or pragmatic coreference
>   for arbitrary PRO), binding (as in the case of wh-movement), or close
>   association (as in the case of it-extraposition). These relationships
>   are shown only when some type of null element is involved, and only
>   when the relationship is intrasentential. One null element may be
>   associated with another, as in the case of the null wh-operator.
>   Coreference relations between overt pronouns and their antecedents are
>   not annotated.

I work quite a lot with POS taggers and I usually just ignore the numbers chained on, unless I am debugging a parse error and want to know why a sentence is tagged wrong. They can be very useful for training sequencing algorithms such as MMEM, CRFs, etc.